# How do I differentiate between synchronic and dialectic approaches?

Tags: marx, dialectic, structuralism

Marx has often been said to be using dialectic method and structuralism synchronic. Can someone, with examples, explain the two terms/approaches to me?

Comment: I made an edit to capitalize "how" and change "some" to "someone". You may roll these back if you think this was inappropriate. Is the phrase "structuralism synchronic" the way this is stated in some reference?  If you have a reference to add that helps with the question. Welcome to this SE!

Answer (score 3):

I think that it has more to do with Synchronic vs Diachronic structuralism. Synchronics look at an idea in a specific time interval while Diachronics look at the evolution of an idea. Atleast as Hegel's and Marx's use "dialectic" is concerned, the dialectical process is concerned with evolution of ideas, and hence diachronic.